# How to split the address from one textbox and show those values in other textboxes?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components, angular-google-maps

[Open the image to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy05c.png)

I want the above address one value to be split in the below textboxes address Two, city and state. So how can I do it?

My code for HTML is as below:

```
<p>                                  
   <label class="w3-text-teal"><b>Address One</b></label>
   <input #search [formControl]="searchControl" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.addressOne" placeholder="Address"
     name="addressOne" minlength="4" maxlength="15" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off">
 </p>
 <div *ngIf="addresone.invalid && (addresone.dirty || addresone.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="addresone.errors.required">
     addresone is required.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="addresone.errors.minlength">
     addresone must be at least 4 characters long.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="addresone.errors.maxlength">
     addresone must be less than 15 characters.
   </div>
 </div>

 <p>
   <label class="w3-text-teal"><b>Address Two</b></label>
   <input #addressTwo="ngModel" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.addressTwo" placeholder="Address"
     name="addressTwo" minlength="4" maxlength="15">
 </p>
 <div *ngIf="addressTwo.invalid && (addressTwo.dirty || addressTwo.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="addressTwo.errors.required">
     addressTwo is required.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="addressTwo.errors.minlength">
     addressTwo must be at least 4 characters long.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="addressTwo.errors.maxlength">
     addressTwo must be less than 15 characters.
   </div>
 </div>
 <p>
   <label class="w3-text-teal"><b>City</b></label>
   <input #city="ngModel" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.city" placeholder="city" name="city"
     minlength="4" maxlength="15">
 </p>
 <div *ngIf="city.invalid && (city.dirty || city.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="city.errors.required">
     city is required.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="city.errors.minlength">
     city must be at least 4 characters long.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="city.errors.maxlength">
     city must be less than 15 characters.
   </div>
 </div>
 <p>
   <label class="w3-text-teal"><b>State</b></label>
   <input #state="ngModel" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.state" placeholder="state"
     name="state"  minlength="4" maxlength="15">
 </p>
 <div *ngIf="state.invalid && (state.dirty || state.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="state.errors.required">
     state is required.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="state.errors.minlength">
     state must be at least 4 characters long.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="state.errors.maxlength">
     state must be less than 15 characters.
   </div>
 </div>
 <p>
   <label class="w3-text-teal"><b>Zip Code</b></label>
   <input #zipCode="ngModel" class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" required [(ngModel)]="model.zipCode" placeholder="zipCode"
     name="zipCode" minlength="4" maxlength="15">
 </p>
 <div *ngIf="zipCode.invalid && (zipCode.dirty || zipCode.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="zipCode.errors.required">
     zipCode is required.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="zipCode.errors.minlength">
     zipCode must be at least 4 characters long.
   </div>
   <div class="w3-text-red" *ngIf="zipCode.errors.maxlength">
     zipCode must be less than 15 characters.
   </div>
 </div>
```

And the code of the controller is as follows:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, NgModule, NgZone, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params, Data } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService } from 'ngx-webstorage';
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
import { AuthenticationUserService } from '../authentication-user.service';
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import {} from '@types/googlemaps';
declare var google:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-company',
  templateUrl: './add-company.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-company.component.css']
})

export class AddCompanyComponent implements OnInit {
  URL;
  public latitude: number;
  public longitude: number;
  public searchControl: FormControl;
  public zoom: number;


  @ViewChild("search")
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;



  subscription1 = {
    users: "",
    period: "",
    price: ""
  };
  model = {
    companyLogo: ""
  };
  base64textString;
  companyId;
  companyName;

  constructor(public http: Http, private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    private ngZone: NgZone, private router: Router, public storage: LocalStorageService,private user:AuthenticationUserService) {
    this.URL = this.storage.retrieve('url');
    this.companyId="59ef5e6c4695460aafd1f8d2";

    this.http.get(this.URL + 'companies/59ef5e6c4695460aafd1f8d2').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      this.model = data;
      this.base64textString = data.companyLogo;
    });
  }


  ngOnInit() {


    this.http.get(this.URL + 'subscriptions').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      this.subscription1 = data;

    });
    //saurabh

      this.URL= this.storage.retrieve('url');
    this.companyName = this.storage.retrieve('companyName');

        this.http.get(this.URL + "Companies?filter[where][email]=" + this.storage.retrieve('email') + "&filter[where][password]=" + this.storage.retrieve('password') +"&filter[where][companyName]=" + this.companyName )
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(isCompany => {
            isCompany.length == 0 ? this.router.navigate([this.companyName]) : this.user.setUserLoggedIn(), this.router.navigate([this.companyName + '/dashboard']);
          });

           //set google maps defaults
    this.zoom = 4;
    this.latitude = 39.8282;
    this.longitude = -98.5795;

    //create search FormControl
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();

    //set current position
    this.setCurrentPosition();

    //load Places Autocomplete
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          //get the place result
          let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          //verify result
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          //set latitude, longitude and zoom
          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 12;
        });
      });
    });

  }

  private setCurrentPosition() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.zoom = 12;
      });
    }
  }


  onSubmit(form) {

    this.http.post(this.URL + 'companies', form).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('success');
    });

    console.log("on submit par");

    console.log(this.base64textString);



  }

  onCancel(form){
    console.log(form);
      this.http.patch(this.URL + 'companies/'+this.companyId, form).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('success');
    });

  }

  onClear() {

  }

//method done by one and only Niraj :)
  imageUpload(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = this._imageReaderLoaded.bind(this);

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  }



  _imageReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
    var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
    this.base64textString = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(binaryString);

    this.model.companyLogo = this.base64textString;

  }


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did it go with the answers, was either suitable for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that parses your address one field and updates your model with what it finds out (i.e. city, state, etc). Call that function after your address one field is edited.

PS: You might want to clarify what exactly if the problem you are having versus asking for help on implementing something for you. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Sorry but I'm also not sure what you are trying to ask here :D

Comment: I am just asking that when I am selecting one address from the drop down in auto complete directive, how can I split that whole address into the text boxes below.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the actual search functionality as a totally separate input field, and instead then show the results from that search in other fields. As for the search result, I assume you get a string like:

```
stringToSplit = 'South Las Vegas Boulevard,NV,United States'
```

To this I would just use [**`String.prototype.split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), which makes your data to a string array, which you can assign to your `model`.

```
this.model = this.stringToSplit.split(',');
```

Then you can just refer your `[(ngModel)]` to the indexes of your newly created array. So for example the following two fields of your form (with some attributes omitted):

```html
<input [formControl]="searchControl"/>
<input [(ngModel)]="model[0]" name="addressOne" #addressOne="ngModel">
<input [(ngModel)]="model[1]" name="addressTwo" #addressTwo="ngModel">
```